# How to post various custom data types using Ajax in MVC3?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, form-data

I have this ViewModel to represent each Category and it's several Sub-Categories in my project:

```
public class Categories
{
    //a simple string for the category name
    [Required]
    public string Cat_Name { get; set; }

    //a list of strings for the sub-categories
    public List<string> SubCat_Name { get; set; }
}
```

I pass this model to the view, and I use it to construct my form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Category", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "Cat" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubName, new { @class = "Sub" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubName, new { @class = "Sub" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubName, new { @class = "Sub" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubName, new { @class = "Sub" })

    <input type="button" value="Create New Category" name="Category" onclick="DoIt()" />
}
```

And as you see, the javascript function "`DoIt()`" is called by the click on the input button.
here's the function :

```
function DoIt() {
    var stringArray = new Array();
    //I put all of the sub-categories inside an array, to be like a list<string>

    $(".Sub").each(function (index, value) {
        stringArray[index] = this.value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/Category',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify($(".Cat").attr("value") , stringArray),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () { console.log("post done"); },
        error: function () { }
    });
}
```

As you can see, in the ajax method I'm trying to pass the "Category Name" `$(".Cat").attr("value")` and it's "Sub-Category Names" `stringArray` to the corresponding action method which requires `Categories` datatype I created as a viewmodel before. It looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Category(Categories CAT)
{
    //Do something
    return View();
}
```

The problem is the ajax method can't post two datatypes at once, or just that I don't know how to do it.

I also tried this :

```
var postdata = {
    Name: $(".Cat").attr("value"),
    SubName: stringArray
};
```

and put `postdata` inside the `JSON.stringify()` instead. But still nothing is passed to the action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are very close.

Try this

```
var postdata = {
    Cat_Name: $(".Cat").val(),
    SubCat_Name: stringArray
};
```

&

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/Category',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(CAT:postdata),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function () { console.log("post done"); },
        error: function () { }
    });
```

Comment: This kinda works.
Of course when I changed `CAT:postdata` to `{CAT:postdata}`, and if the `stringArray` is null !!!
Whenever I set some values into the `stringArray` the ajax code fails to post the data.
Weird !

Answer (score 1):

Try to send data formatted like this:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/Category',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ Cat_Name: $(".Cat").val(), SubCat_Name: stringArray }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () { console.log("post done"); },
        error: function () { }
    });
```

Comment: It does send the data, but if I change the datatype the action method receives to string or List<string> ...

Comment: the action method should look like the one above, could you specify the problem?

Comment: Ajax code doesn't seem to post anything to the action method, or maybe the action method can't receive the data, when everything look like above.

They only work fine when I post a `List<string>` and receive the same List<string> in the action method. Currently I'm doing without the model. I'm just sending everything in an array, receiving `List<string>` in action method side. It works. but it's not a good solution.

Comment: Here you have an example app that uses above code: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1171045/11904224.zip

Comment: Thanks !
I finally made it :D

Comment: The problem was with the naming convention and overall formatting of the json I was trying to send ;)